# Using Feeds Importer to Import YouTube video uploads (API 3.0)

Tags: 7, feeds, files

Here is my scenario:

I am using Feeds module, Google Auth module, and Media module. I am trying to import a list of recently uploaded videos to a specific channel (maintained by me) using the above.

While this is fairly simple in YouTube API 2.0, I'm having a very difficult time trying to figure out how to do this with 3.0.

Since 2.0 is deprecated, the methods for that is not working (obviously), and I've tried authenticating my API (already done), putting in the info into Google Auth module (already done), and using the example codes to generate a URL to put into Feeds importer (already done but not working).

I keep getting a 200 OK with the example code on Google's API -- using the channel function, but 400 (forbidden) when putting it into Feed importer, so I know there is a permissions issue somewhere, but I can't figure out where.

I also don't know for sure if this method is the correct method to do this.

Any help or suggestions would be great. I'm at my wits end about this and I feel like I'm just missing some important piece but can't see it at all.

Comment: What url are you using to import from youtube?